# Overloaded Operator for a templated AVLTree issues

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, find, avl-tree

I am currently working on creating an templated AVLTree, and have the structure down and now am trying to implement a find and contains function for the tree. I have stumbled into an issue with overloading operators with a two-type template class. Currently, I can only get the root of the tree but none of the leaves. I was hoping to get some guidance. My main question is, is there a way to implement the find without overloading an operator, and if not - can I get some guidance as to where I am currently going wrong.

Below I have attached the structure of my tree, the find function I am currently working on and my attempt to overload the == operator.

```
template <typename t, typename s>
class DSAVLTree{
private:
    template <typename n, typename b>
    class AVLNode{
    public:
        n data;
        b vectorToBe;
        AVLNode* left;
        AVLNode* right;
        int height; //determine balance

        AVLNode(const n &element, const b &vector, AVLNode<n, b> *lefty, AVLNode<n, b> *righty, int h = 0):
        data(element), vectorToBe(vector), left(lefty), right(righty), height(h){};
    };

    AVLNode<t, s> *root;
public:

    DSAVLTree(): root(nullptr){};
    DSAVLTree(const DSAVLTree<t, s> &rhs): root(nullptr){
        *this = right;
    }
    ~DSAVLTree(){
        emptyify(root);
    }

//HERE I REMOVED THE BALANCE AND CASES

AVLNode<t,s>* find(t data){
        return find(root, data);
    }

    AVLNode<t,s>* find(AVLNode<t, s> *tree, t dta){
        if(tree == nullptr){
            return nullptr;
        }

        else if(tree->data == dta){
            return tree;
        }

        else if (dta < tree -> data){
            return(find(tree -> left, dta));
        }

        else{
            return find(tree -> right,dta);
        }
    }

bool operator==(const DSAVLTree<t,s>& otherTree) const{
        return (otherTree.root == nullptr && root == 0);
    }
```

Comment: Your find function look OK, and since it does not make any calls to any operators, that should answer your question.   There is a call to a copy operator in the copy constructor, is tat what you were referring to?  There is no need to declare the inner type AVLNode as a template, it adds unnecessary complexity to your code.

Comment: Well, you need an `operator<` defined for your type parameter `n`, but I don't see anywhere else operator overloading would be relevant. Since you seem already to have implemented find without overloading any other operators, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sure, your `operator==` looks fishy, but that has nothing to do with being a templated entity. Furthermore, your `operator==` is not used by your `find` method, nor do I see why it would. Similarly, I do not see why it would be used in your (not shown) `contains` method. So why are you bundling all of these together into one question? You should probably focus on your `find` method and show us an example where it does not work.